# hyperref error in case some class option is given at load time

Tags: hyperref, color, l3keys

In the MCE below, everything works as expected:

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{myclass.cls}
\ProvidesExplClass{myclass}{2022-06-15}{0.1}{Class of mine}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\LoadClass { article }    

\RequirePackage{l3keys2e}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}

\clist_const:Nn \c__myclass_default_pagecolor_clist {1.0, 0.98, 0.94}

\definecolor{myclass_pagecolor}{rgb}{\c__myclass_default_pagecolor_clist}

\keys_define:nn { myclass }{ 
   pagecolor .code:n = {  \definecolor{myclass_pagecolor}{rgb}{#1} } }

\ProcessKeysOptions { myclass }

\AddToHook{begindocument/before}{ \pagecolor{myclass_pagecolor} }

\NewDocumentCommand \myclasssetup { m } { \keys_set:nn { myclass } { #1 } }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass%
% [pagecolor={0.5, 0.98, 0.94}]
{myclass}
\myclasssetup{pagecolor={0.5, 0.98, 0.94}}
\begin{document}
Foo
\end{document}
```

but, as soon as the load-time class option `[pagecolor={0.5, 0.98, 0.94}]` is uncommented, the compilation fails with the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.4020 \ProcessKeyvalOptions{Hyp}
```

It may be helpful to notice that, if the colors are defined thanks to `\colorlet` instead of `\definecolor`, the issue doesn't arise:

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{myclass.cls}
\ProvidesExplClass{myclass}{2022-06-15}{0.1}{Class of mine}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\LoadClass { article }

\RequirePackage{l3keys2e}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}

\tl_const:Nn \c__myclass_default_pagecolor_tl {cyan}

\colorlet{myclass_pagecolor}{\c__myclass_default_pagecolor_tl}

\keys_define:nn { myclass } {
  pagecolor .code:n = { \colorlet{myclass_pagecolor}{#1} }  }

\ProcessKeysOptions { myclass }

\AddToHook{begindocument/before}{ \pagecolor{myclass_pagecolor} }

\NewDocumentCommand \myclasssetup { m } { \keys_set:nn { myclass } { #1 } }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass%
[pagecolor=yellow]
{myclass}
% \myclasssetup{pagecolor=yellow}
\begin{document}
Foo
\end{document}
```

What's going on?

Comment: hyperref knows an option pagecolor too, and after the processing it tries to remove it from the unused option list and this fails badly because of the braces in the option. `pagecolor={yellow}` would error too. Better don't setup such class options. Even if I would change hyperref, there are other packages ...

Comment: Before posting, I had a look at the `hyperref` documentation but couldn't find any `pagecolor` option. But I'll follow your advice.

Comment: the option has been disabled in hyperref, it does nothing. But the key is processed. But I'm discussing it with David.

Comment: we'll fix this (if you look in chat you'll see some code) but you have a missing `\ ` in `\definecolor` here `pagecolor .code:n = {  definecolor{myclass_pagecolor}{rgb}{#1} } }`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks and sorry for the typo (fixed).

Comment: @DenisBitouzé I uploaded an update for kvoptions, but e.g. xkeyval has a similar problem (I wrote the author) and probably more keyval handler. so better avoid braces if possible.